# Should we have a trivia tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by this question:

[Which games have ever been rated #1 on Boardgamegeek.com's Geek Rating?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31396/which-games-have-ever-been-rated-1-on-boardgamegeek-coms-geek-rating)

The Sports.SE has a `trivia` tag with the following description:

> For questions generally relating to small, specific facts regarding a player, team, or game that are not common knowledge. Questions should also be tagged with the sport referenced.

The above question seems to me to be trivia related, although not about a specific game. While the Sports.SE tag is generally paired with another tag, a `trivia` tag on B&CG.SE wouldn't have to be.

Answer (score 9):

**We should allow trivia questions, but not introduce a tag for it.**

I borrowed justification from [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), by Jeff Atwood. The [trivia](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag is a meta tag. It describes a particular "kind" of question, but does not tell you what the question is actually about. It could not stand alone as the only tag on a question. In other words, every single question tagged [trivia](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) will require a supporting tag (like chess trivia, or Magic: the Gathering trivia).

The Sports community skipped a step when they were discussing trivia. After looking at their meta discussion from years ago, it looks like this happened:

> "Should we allow Sports trivia?"
>   "Yes, we should, but let's make some rules so that we only have good trivia."
>   *The [trivia](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag is born.*

But hold on a second! Nobody bothered to ask...

> "Do we make a tag for it?"

It does not follow that just because a particular breed of question is on topic that we need a tag for it.

We do not we need to generate any sort of rules like Sports SE. Easily searchable trivia will be downvoted for lack of research effort. Subjective trivia will be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Tangentially, what should the question I linked be tagged with?

Comment: @SocioMatt If the question were on topic, I would tag it [tag:board-game-geek]. See my comment on the question for why I believe it is off topic. I did my best to answer your question without dwelling too much on the example you used - it frustrates me when people do that to me.

Comment: I think your answer makes sense in the context of trivia as a tag. I just curious as to what would be as acceptable solution if there was no such tag.

Comment: @SocioMatt A solution to... what? I'm not sure that I understand the problem we are trying to solve. Do we *need* to properly tag questions that are off topic?

Comment: It depends on whether it actually gets closed as off-topic.

Comment: @SocioMatt You misread my question. Do we need to properly tag questions **that are off topic**? Without the bold part, yes, it would depend.

Comment: I have no idea whether that is necessary or not. On one hand, even closed questions should sort into the set of site-standards that have been created. On the other, if they are going to be deleted quickly after being closed, then it might not be worth the effort. That may be another meta question.

Comment: My question was intended to be rhetorical. We do not need tags for off topic questions. Go ahead and ask a meta question about it if you want, but I can already tell you that that is the answer you'll probably get.

Comment: @Rainbolt I agree strongly enough on tagging it with board-game-geek that I've [added that tag](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/31396/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

### No. We might need it later.

On a games site, the tag "trivia" seems better used for games like *Trivial Pursuit* where the gameplay involves the recall of specific facts. It's analogous to [party](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party).